# Matlab + Armadillo and the inverse matrix crashes

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, mex, armadillo, matrix-inverse

I'm trying calculate a inverse matrix from Matlab using Armadillo lib. To do this I'm using Mex. Unfortunately, Matlab crashes when I call the function. Looking at my code, someone can help where am I wrong?

```
#include "armaMex.hpp"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
             int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{   
    mat A = armaGetPr(prhs[0]);
    plhs[0] = armaCreateMxMatrix(A.n_rows,A.n_cols);
    armaSetPr(plhs[0],inv(A)); 
}
```

It compiles without errors.

Comment: Can you edit to show the error message seen when Matlab crashes? Can't tell if the problem is numerical or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include "armaMex.hpp"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
         int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{   
    mat A =  conv_to<mat>::from(armaGetPr(prhs[0],true));

    plhs[0] = armaCreateMxMatrix(A.n_rows,A.n_cols, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    armaSetPr(plhs[0],conv_to<mat>::from(inv(A))); 

}
```